# Email reply - text does not add

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm writting macro that finds an e-mail and replies to it. The problem is that the text I want to reply with does not add. Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
 Sub Test()

 Dim olApp As Object
 Dim olNs As Object
 Dim Fldr As Object
 Dim i As Long

 Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Test")

i = 1

For Each olMail In olNs.Items
If InStr(olMail.Subject, "kanapka") <> 0 Then

    With olMail.ReplyAll

    .CC = "xyz@xyz"
    .Body = "Dear All," _ 
    & vbCrLf & "aaaaaa" 'these two lines should add
    olMail.Reply.Display

    End With


i = i + 1

End If


Next olMail

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your code:

```
For Each olMail In olNs.Items
    If InStr(olMail.Subject, "testme") <> 0 Then
        Set oReply = olMail.Reply
        Set oRecip = oReply.Recipients.Add("x@y.z")
        oRecip.Type = olCC
        oReply.HTMLBody = "Thank you!!!" & oReply.HTMLBody
        oReply.Display
        Stop ' - remove this once you try the code.
    End If
Next olMail
```

As you see, you have to declare `oReply` and `oRecip` as Objects, but these two make your life really easier.
In order to add some text to the answer, simply increment the body this way:

```
oReply.HTMLBody = "Thank you!!!" & oReply.HTMLBody
```

I have also included a `Stop` in your code, to make sure that it does not display plenty of emails.